# How to make VirtualBox shared folder appear as local drive on guest?

Tags: virtualbox

The host is Windows 10. The guest can be either Windows (preferable) or Linux.
I know at least it's possible for a Linux guest because I use Vagrant and it maps the shared folders as local folders. How do I achieve that if not using Vagrant?

Comment: [`mount -t vboxsf …`](https://askubuntu.com/a/161883/693277)

Comment: That does not show up as a local drive/folder

Comment: What do you mean by "local"? Linux shouldn't care. If it's mounted then you can use the files.

Comment: I want to use BackBlaze on the VM so it needs to appear as a local drive